# Some images do not load under http, but do under https

Tags: ssl, image, iis-6

I've come across an issue where some images on a site load under https but do not load under http.

For example if you go to https://www.mydomain.com/myimage.gif, the image appears fine, but if you go to http://www.mydomain.com/myimage.gif the image comes back with a not found error.  This happens to only certain images.  Other images load fine either way.  Even images in the same directory as the problem images load fine.

I know that if SSL is not set up correctly I've seen a similar issue, but it's always been with the entire site, not with a few images.

This is on an IIS6 server.

Comment: Is this behavior consistent across browsers and/or PCs/Macs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.  It turns out that the https site was created using a physical copy of the actual site under the SSL port, this means there were 2 versions of the site being served under the same domain name, one under port 80 and one under port 443.

The issue appeared because someone updated the port 443 site.  The images missing in the port 80 site were actually not there, causing the 404 error.

Thanks for the help.  Too bad this got modded down... I guess this question is not strictly a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

Moving a comment out to answer in the hopes it'll get a response:

> Is this behavior consistent across browsers and/or PCs/Macs?

Comment: This happens in all the browsers an OSes I've tested on.  Vista and XP, IE6, IE7, Safari, Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Fiddler to see what is happening with that particular image when the page is loaded.

Comment: Good idea.  I'm beginning to think the issue is permissions, but I don't see why it would be different if you access it via https vs http.